# What is this AssertionError trying to tell me and how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement an artificial neural network (autoencoder) on my dataset. The error I mentioned is occurring in the fit statement. All the data sets referenced in the code are numpy.ndarrays of float64 type.

The data set was a dataframe initially and then after I split it into train and test I converted them into ndarrays because I believe that's required to run the autoencoder code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, classification_report, auc, roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, f1_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from pylab import rcParams
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from keras import regularizers

attempt = ads

msk = np.random.rand(len(attempt)) < 0.8
train_x = attempt[msk]
test_x = attempt[~msk]

train_x = train_x[train_x.Successful_Quote == 0] #where normal transactions
train_x = train_x.drop(['Successful_Quote'], axis=1) #drop the class column

test_y = test_x['Successful_Quote'] #save the class column for the test set
test_x = test_x.drop(['Successful_Quote'], axis=1) #drop the class column

train_x = train_x.values #transform to ndarray
test_x = test_x.values

nb_epoch = 100
batch_size = 128
input_dim = train_x.shape[1] #num of columns, 30
encoding_dim = 14
hidden_dim = int(encoding_dim / 2) #i.e. 7
learning_rate = 1e-7

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))
encoder = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="tanh", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(learning_rate))(input_layer)
encoder = Dense(hidden_dim, activation="relu")(encoder)
decoder = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='tanh')(encoder)
decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation='relu')(decoder)
autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder)

autoencoder.compile(metrics=['accuracy'],
                    loss='mean_squared_error',
                    optimizer='adam')

cp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=r"C:\Users\kartik.kumar\Desktop\Pricing Project",
                               save_best_only=True,
                               verbose=0)

tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs',
                histogram_freq=0,
                write_graph=True,
                write_images=True)

history = autoencoder.fit(train_x, train_x,
                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(test_x, test_x),
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[cp, tb]).history
```

Error message:

```
Train on 4203 samples, validate on 1517 samples
Epoch 1/100
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-153-aea5b9ca41ad>", line 7, in <module>
    callbacks=[cp, tb]).history

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 176, in fit_loop
    np.random.shuffle(index_array)

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4823, in mtrand.RandomState.shuffle

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_internal.py", line 298, in __init__
    assert self._data.value == ptr

AssertionError
```

line 298 mentioned in the traceback leads to this:

```
    if ctypes:
     self._ctypes = ctypes
     # get a void pointer to the buffer, which keeps the array alive
     self._data = _get_void_ptr(array)
     assert self._data.value == ptr
    else:
     # fake a pointer-like object that holds onto the reference
     self._ctypes = _missing_ctypes()
     self._data = self._ctypes.c_void_p(ptr)
     self._data._objects = array
```

I expected the output to start training the model and give me something like this:

```
Train on 227468 samples, validate on 56962 samples
Epoch 1/100
227468/227468 [==============================] - 7s 29us/step - loss: 0.8688 - acc: 0.4782 - val_loss: 0.8266 - val_acc: 0.5893
Epoch 2/100
227468/227468 [==============================] - 5s 20us/step - loss: 0.7767 - acc: 0.6053 - val_loss: 0.7980 - val_acc: 0.6191
Epoch 3/100
227468/227468 [==============================] - 4s 19us/step - loss: 0.7575 - acc: 0.6291 - val_loss: 0.7855 - val_acc: 0.6376
Epoch 4/100
227468/227468 [==============================] - 4s 19us/step - loss: 0.7473 - acc: 0.6395 - val_loss: 0.7781 - val_acc: 0.6412
```

My only guess is there is an issue with the datatypes that I've used here.

Not sure if this is helpful, but: My python version is 3.7 and I'm using the latest tensorflow, keras, numpy and sklearn libraries.

I'm getting the same error when I run this as well:

```
RANDOM_SEED = 314 #used to help randomly select the data points
TEST_PCT = 0.2 # 20% of the data
train_x, test_x = train_test_split(attempt, test_size=TEST_PCT, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
```

Comment: What's cp and tb in [cp, tb]?

Comment: Updated code with their definitions

Comment: Are you able to  run above code if not using `callbacks=[cp, tb]` ?

Comment: No, I got the same error.

Comment: And If you don't use history.

Comment: Tried that as well, same error.

Comment: You say you're using latest libraries but still combine `keras` with `tensorflow` while you should be using `tensorflow.keras` instead. That could be an issue. Anyway full code will give more information. I highly suggest moving from `keras` to `tf.keras`.

Comment: Updated with complete code

Comment: I have added the import statements. Sure, I can test out the code. Please PM it to me?

Comment: Your code is running in my laptop. Tensorflow  '1.12.0' , keras '2.2.3' python 3.5 anaconda

Comment: Do you think it's an issue with my installation? I have Tensorflow '1.13.0' and Python 3.7

Comment: Also, I have added one more example of when this error is occurring, it's a simple usage of train_test_split()

Comment: Try tensorflow.keras in place of keras everywhere. just give it a try

Comment: Also `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` and `tf.keras.callbacks.Tensorboard`

Comment: It looks like keras is not installed correctly. So try these steps first.

Comment: I restarted kernel in order to try something out. Loading all the datasets again, will try these and let you know. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Yup, I made the changes you asked me to and it's working now. Can you help me understand what went wrong?